# svg анимация тормозит в FF

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animation

Имею анимированные wave svg:

```
<svg class="wave" width="1920" height="724" viewBox="0 0 1920 724" fill="none" xmlns="//www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path class="wave-path wave-path-1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 472L80 460C160 448 320 424 480 448C640 472 800 544 960 592C1120 640 1280 664 1440 634C1600 604 1760 520 1840 478L1920 436V724H1840C1760 724 1600 724 1440 724C1280 724 1120 724 960 724C800 724 640 724 480 724C320 724 160 724 80 724H0V472Z"/>
            <path class="wave-path wave-path-2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 724L80 657C160 590 320 455 480 407C640 359 800 398 960 426C1120 455 1280 474 1440 436C1600 398 1760 302 1840 254L1920 206V724H1840C1760 724 1600 724 1440 724C1280 724 1120 724 960 724C800 724 640 724 480 724C320 724 160 724 80 724H0Z"/>
            <path class="wave-path wave-path-3" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 436.327L80 474.327C160 513.327 320 590.327 480 599.327C640 609.327 800 551.327 960 503.327C1120 455.327 1280 417.327 1440 426.327C1600 436.327 1760 494.327 1840 522.327L1920 551.327V724.327H1840C1760 724.327 1600 724.327 1440 724.327C1280 724.327 1120 724.327 960 724.327C800 724.327 640 724.327 480 724.327C320 724.327 160 724.327 80 724.327H0V436.327Z"/>
        </svg>
```

css:

```
.wave {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
pointer-events: none;
}

.wave .wave-path-1 {
-webkit-animation: wave1 15s ease-in-out infinite;
animation: wave1 15s ease-in-out infinite;
fill: rgba(96, 138, 223, .1);
}

.wave .wave-path-2 {
-webkit-animation: wave2 15s ease-in-out infinite;
animation: wave2 15s ease-in-out infinite;
fill: rgb(140, 179, 255, .1);
}

.wave .wave-path-3 {
-webkit-animation: wave3 15s ease-in-out infinite;
animation: wave3 15s ease-in-out infinite;
fill: rgb(102, 153, 255, .1);
}

.wave .wave-path {
transform: scale(1.2, 1);
transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

@keyframes wave1 {
25% {
    transform: scale(1.4, 1.3);
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
75% {
    transform: scale(1.4, .7);
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
}


@keyframes wave2 {
25% {
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
50% {
    transform: scale(1.3, .8);
}
75% {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
}

@keyframes wave3 {
25% {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
50% {
    transform: scale(1.2, .9);
}
75% {
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
}
```

В хроме анимация идет хорошо, в отличии от FF, там она немного подлагивает. Подскажите, можно ли исправить? Видел решение, мол нужно svg переписать в webgl, но не понял как и где. (@-webkit-keyframes добавлен).

Хочу заметить, что такая проблема у меня при развернутой странички на весь экран. В мобильной или планшетной версии всё нормально. Может, проблема в широкоформатном мониторе?

Comment: а если прозрачность слоёв убрать результат такой же?

Comment: Да. Так же. Особенно подлагивает при скроллинге страницы

Comment: Я как-то столкнулся с тормозами svg в динамике, пришлось переделать конкретное место на канвас.